# PBI Measure separates column values into rows

Tags: powerbi

When adding a measure to a table in Power BI, the values in my first column get broken up into more than one grouped row. It appears as if one of the other column values are being grouped as soon as I bring in the measure. See attached image.
[table and measure example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki1bB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check every column you did put into your table visual and check this option:

[image]

Comment: Yes, all fields/columns selected are on "Don't summarize" yet the issue persists.

Comment: Column D of yours is not a measure. It is a calculated column in DAX, therefore it applies on every row on your table. So in a table with the calculated column you see every row (like in your screenshot) and in a table without the calculated column there are grouped if you dont ungroup them like stated above. As far as I see everything is fine.

Comment: you are right, it is a calc column, but the measure i had created gave me the same percentage across all rows. i unjoined & deleted some tables and it seems to have helped. Now my actual measure is calculating correctly. thank you for the feedback!